# Is this $3\times 3$ matrix positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have three non-null and non-parallel column vectors $z_i \in \mathbb{R}^3$, and I have the next symmetric matrix:

$$
M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
||z_1||^2 & z_1^Tz_2 & z_1^Tz_3 \\
z_2^Tz_1 & ||z_2||^2 & z_2^Tz_3 \\
z_3^Tz_1 & z_3^Tz_2 & ||z_3||^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Looking at the two first principal minors, they are positive since
$$
||z_1||^2 > 0, \quad ||z_1||^2\,||z_2||^2 > ||z_1^Tz_2||^2
$$

I suspect that the 
$$
det(M) = ||z_1||^2\, ||z_2||^2\, ||z_3||^2 + 2\,z_1^Tz_2 z_2^Tz_3z_3^Tz_1 - ||z_1||^2(z_2^Tz_3)^2 - ||z_2||^2(z_1^Tz_3)^2 - ||z_3||^2(z_2^Tz_1)^2
$$
is also positive, but I can not see how to prove it (or to find a counter-example). Any hints?

I suspect that this article is what I am looking for: 
https://secure.ele-math.com/buy/mia-11-52 
but I can not check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$Z := \begin{bmatrix} z_1 & z_2 & z_3 \end{bmatrix}.$$

What would be $Z^T Z$?

Comment: It would be M which is the Grammian matrix, therefore $Z^TZ$ is positive definite under my assumptions for $z_i$?

Comment: Almost. $Z^TZ$ is always positive semidefinite (for any real matrix $Z$). However, it is (strictly) positive definite if and only if the columns of $Z$ are linearly independent. To me, your "non-parallel" sound like no two of them are linearly independent, but all three can still be. For example, vectors $z_1 := e_1 = [1,0,0]^T$, $z_2 := e_2 = [0,1,0]^T$, and $z_3 := e_1+e_2 = [1,1,0]$ seem "non-parallel" to me, but they are obviously linearly dependent and if you use them above, $M$ will be positive semidefinite, but not (strictly) positive definite.

Comment: Thank you so much for your hint, you are right. I have to change the condition to non-parallel to linearly independent indeed.